# PERL: How to redirect STDOUT of a script inside a wrapper

Tags: perl, redirect, wrapper, stdout

I want to make a perl script which gonna be a wrapper to another script. 
Inside my wrapper, I run the "other script" with some parameters. This "other script" should print quite a lot of runtime data to the STDOUT.
So, how do I let the "some script" print the data to STDOUT immediately when I run it inside my perl wrapper? (I don't want any files/variables only the STDOUT)

Thank you for your answers in advance!

Comment: Please add to the question some of your hypothetical code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call your command with system() then the stdout will go to stdout.

eg:

```
perl -e "system('ls');"
```